Theorem $10.21$ in Kunen, chapter $1$.
Theorem $10.21$ in chapter $1$ of Kunen is stated as follows (paraphrasing; have added some information that is spelled out elsewhere in Kunen):

Assume choice. Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal (so $\kappa \geq \omega$), and let $|X_{\alpha}| \leq \kappa$. Then $$\left|\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha}\right| \leq \kappa.$$

I will give you the (quite short; with som added notation to make it more easy to understand what I am asking) proof of Kunen below:

Pick a $1$-$1$ map $f_{\alpha}$ from $X_{\alpha}$ into $\kappa$. Use these to define a an injective map $$g:\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha} \to \kappa \times \kappa.$$ The $f_{\alpha}$ are picked using a well-order on $\mathscr{P}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha} \times \kappa \right)$.

It is the last sentence I am having trouble with understanding. My guess is that we want to define sets $S_{x} = \{(x,\beta) \;|\; x \in X_{\beta}\}$ and then pick the $\in$-least element of them (with respect to the second argument), so that we then define $$g(x) = (\alpha,f_{\alpha}(x))$$ where $\alpha$ is the $\in$-least element of $S_{x}$ with respect to the second argument. But I am having trouble understanding how to choose $R$ (if I need to do it explicitly, that is; I am unsure).
I believe I understand the rest of the proof, but I would be really glad to be enlightened how to pick the $f_{\alpha}$.
Another comment: What I fail to realize is why we are looking at $$\mathscr{P}\left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha} \times \kappa\right)$$ and not $$\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha} \times \kappa$$ since the sets $S_{x}$ that I defined above is are elements of the former but subsets of the latter (so they will have an $R$-least element in the latter but not neccessarily in the former). Unless they mean that we choose a well-order $R$ from the former.

Perhaps this works: Let $X = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha}$ and let $M_{x} = {\beta \in \kappa: x \in X_{\beta}} \subseteq \kappa$. Then by assumption $M_{x} \neq \varnothing, \forall x \in X$. Define $\phi:X \to \kappa$ by $\phi(x) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the $\in$-least element of $M_{x}$. Then define $g:X \to \kappa \times \kappa$ as $g(x) = (\phi(x),f_{\phi(x)}(x))$.

We need a single parameter to make all the choices with. Since every $f_\alpha$ is a subset of $X_\alpha\times\kappa$, it follows that all of them are subsets of $\mathcal P(\bigcup X_\alpha\times\kappa)$.
So, by well-ordering the entirety of the power set we can choose $f_\alpha$ uniformly as the least one in that well-order which does the job.

An alternative approach to this is to simply consider $I_\alpha=\{f\colon X_\alpha\to\kappa\mid f\text{ is injective}\}$, which by the assumption is a non-empty set, and then apply the Axiom of Choice to the family $\{I_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$, which exists since the function $\alpha\mapsto I_\alpha$ is definable (from the parameter which is the family $\{X_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ of course).

Thanks; I don't see what is wrong with the approach I took in my comment. Was there something there you disagreed with?

You're defining sets $S_x$, which can be more neatly written as $S_x={\beta<\kappa\mid x\in X_\beta}$. Now you want to choose the least from each $S_x$, which is fine, and that gives you a family of pairwise disjoint sets whose union is the same union as the $X_\alpha$, but you still need to choose injections from those sets into $\kappa$. Suppose your family was already pairwise disjoint, then ${x\mid\min S_x=\beta}=X_\beta$ for all $\beta<\kappa$. You've gained nothing here.

It follows from $|X_{\alpha}| \leq \kappa$ that there exists an injection $f_{\alpha}:X_{\alpha} \to \kappa$? So why not choose an arbitrary such $f_{\alpha}$, and then define $g(x) = (\phi(x),f_{\phi(x)}(x))$. I am not sure what you are objecting to. Also, my $S_{x}$ are not neccessarily pairwise disjoint, so I am not sure what you are referring to.

Ops, my bad. I realized that how I defined them here is not how I defined them in what I wrote down privately. But yes, I would define them as you do, i.e. $S_{x} = {\beta < \kappa ;|; x \in X_{\beta}}$. Defining $S_{x}$ in this way, I don't see the issue. But I am at work, perhaps I can look at it more closely later, perhaps. Anyways, thanks for engaging!

Oh, perhaps I see the issue, hm, right.

Choose an arbitrary one? For each one? For infinitely many sets? Sounds to me like this is where the Axiom of Choice gets involved...

Yep, I was confused.

Thanks Asaf for your answer; I've accepted it, I'll just expand a little on how I think about this (sanity check!).
Consider $I_{\alpha} := \{f:X_{\alpha} \to \kappa\}$. We know that each such set is non-empty since $|X_{\kappa}| \leq |\kappa| = \kappa$ ($\kappa$ being a cardinal).
We get an indexed family of sets $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \kappa}$. Directly from choice, we see that we can form $(f_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \kappa}$ so that $f_{\alpha} \in I_{\alpha}, \forall \alpha \in \kappa$.
Let $X = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha}$ and let $M_{x} = \{\beta < \kappa: x \in X_{\beta}\} \subseteq \kappa$. Then by assumption $M_{x} \neq \varnothing, \forall x \in X$. Define $\phi:X \to \kappa$ by $\phi(x) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the $\in$-least element of $M_{x}$. Then define $g:X \to \kappa \times \kappa$ as $g(x) = (\phi(x),f_{\phi(x)}(x))$.
One can show that  $g$ is an injection, so that we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} X_{\alpha} \right| &\leq |\kappa \times \kappa|\\
&= \kappa \otimes \kappa\\
&= \kappa.
\end{align*}

Yeah, that's absolutely fine.
